# Radio buttons deselect when I press anywhere else on page

Tags: html, radio-button

I have created simple radio buttons so that the user can select the color they like. It worked for a while but has now stopped keeping the selected option. After selecting one, the option deselects itself when I press any other part of the page.

I never had the attribute 'name' of them the same before but they were working so I thought that might have been the issue that didn't solve it either.

```
              <form name="newActivity" method="post" action="newActivity.php">
                <?php include('errors.php'); ?>
              <label class="colour-title">COLOUR</label>
              <div class="select">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="colour" value="blue">
                    <span class="blue">BLUE</span>
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="colour" value="purple">
                    <span class="purple">PURPLE</span>
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="colour" value="pink">
                    <span class="pink">PINK</span>
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="colour" value="green">
                    <span class="green">GREEN</span>
                </label>
              </div>
```

My radio buttons are also part of a form as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

use id instead of class

The only difference between them is that “id” is unique in a page and can only apply to at most one element, while “class” selector can apply to multiple elements.

example

```
 <form name="newActivity" method="post" action="newActivity.php">
                <?php include('errors.php'); ?>
              <label class="colour-title">COLOUR</label>
              <div class="select">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="colour" value="blue">
                    <span id="btn-color">BLUE</span>
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="colour" value="purple">
                    <span id="btn-color">PURPLE</span>
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="colour" value="pink">
                    <span id="btn-color">PINK</span>
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="colour" value="green">
                    <span id="btn-color">GREEN</span>
                </label>
              </div>
```

Comment: Update: It works and registers the colour chosen however the web page deselects the option whenever it is selected. Why could that be?